# How can I make up cloth in marvelous designer and simulate in blender

Tags: modeling

marvelous designer export cloth is not sew together, and once I simulate in blender they will split and fall down

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, the patches which are generated and simulated in marvelous designer are not welded. 
What I mean is: you have vertices and edges which are sharing the same location but they are not attached to each other.

To correct your mesh in blender, go to editmode, select everything, press <kbd>w</kbd> and pick "remove doubles".

Comment: Thanks,actually I merge them when exporting from MD and it is done